# xsd unique constraint is Invalid

Tags: xsd, unique-constraint

I have seen a lot of examples showing how to use the unique element in an xsd schema, but I don't succeed to make it works for me.
The error I have testing with http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html (if you know a better tool for testing let me know) is: "The Content Of 'schema' Is Invalid. Element 'unique' Is Invalid, Misplaced, Or Occurs Too Often."

XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:inf="http://www.example.net/inflation" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:instrument="http://www.example.net/Instrument" targetNamespace="http://www.example.net/inflation" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://www.example.net/Instrument" schemaLocation="instrument.xsd"/>
    <xsd:element name="inflations" type="inf:Inflations"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="Inflations">
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="historyTable" type="xsd:string" default="INFLATION_HISTORY"/>
          <xsd:element name="inflationHistory" type="inf:InflationHistory" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="InflationHistory">
       <xsd:sequence>
          <xsd:element name="identifier" type="integer"/>
          <xsd:element name="inflation" type="inf:Inflation" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
       </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>


  <!-- Uniqueness -->
  <xsd:unique name="CodeUniqueKey">
    <xsd:selector xpath="inf:inflationHistory" />
    <xsd:field xpath="inf:identifier" />
  </xsd:unique>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A unique constraint has to go inside an element declaration, so:

```
<xsd:element name="inflations" type="inf:Inflations>
  <xsd:unique name="CodeUniqueKey">
    ...
  </xsd:unique>
</xsd:element>
```

Comment: Why does a unique constraint has to go inside an element ? I don't get the logic behind ?
Does the element matter ? Or any element is just fine ?

Comment: @taktak004 think of the containing element declaration as the "scope" of the uniqueness constraint, i.e. the group within which things must be unique.  The constraint says "all the `inflationHistory` elements within the same `inflations` parent must have different `identifier` values".  In this case that means they must be globally unique as the schema only declares one global element, but in general scoping makes sense, e.g. the classic book store example, you might want to ensure all books on one shelf have different names, but allow the same name on different shelves.